# StringTokenizer Not Viewing Tab ("\t") as Whitespace ("\\s+")

Tags: java, split, stringtokenizer

Given a string in the form of:

```
String myStr = "5.1\t3.5\t1.4\t0.2\t0.0";
```

If I call:

```
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(myStr, "\\s+");
String firstElement = token.nextToken();
```

firstElement then equals the whole string.  In contrast, if I call:

```
StringTokenizer token2 = new StringTokenizer(myStr);
String firstElement = token2.nextToken();
```

firstElement equals "5.1".  Similarly if I use String split as below:

```
String[] splitArray = myStr.split("\\s+")
String firstElement = splitArray[0];
```

then, firstElement is "5.1".

I understand StringTokenizer is discouraged for use and is a classified as a "legacy class".  My intent here is to understand why the same delimiter works differently between split and StringTokenizer.  I would have expected the first example to work like the latter two, but for some reason, it is skipping the tabs.  Any guidance on what I am missing would be much appreciated.

Note I am running 1.7.0_19 on OSX in Eclipse, but I would not expect those variables to have an effect here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringTokenizer` doesn't use a regular expression as the delimiters. The parameter is a string containing a list of delimiter characters.

The constructor `StringTokenizer(String)` is same as `StringTokenizer(String, "\t\n\f\r")` hence it works for your string.

Comment: The use of StringTokenizer with "\\s+" is based off this Hadoop Tutorial from MapR.  I assume then this is in error. https://www.mapr.com/blog/how-write-mapreduce-program#.VfZblvlVhBc

Answer (score 1):

**StringTokenizer:** it uses delimiters as string which may contain list of delimiter characters  not as `regex`

[image]

**Split:** it uses delimiters as `regex`

[image]

Comment: For those like me who were not too savvy on regular expressions, I found this helpful.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html